# React Native ScrollView cropping last elements on Android Landscape

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to create a component with a list of elements inside a ScrollView. When i see it in portrait mode everything works perfect but in landscape the last elements are being cropped from the list. This only happens with the compiled APK. I'm using React Native 0.57 and Expo 31.0.4.

I've tried several style settings (percentages, flex) and also tried to change the ScrollView component to a FlatList

[You can find a example code here](https://snack.expo.io/@ispcloudservices/c2ltcG)

Please note in the simulators everything works fine, the problem happens when you build the APK and install it on a device

The screen shoud view like in the [portrait mode](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P3WDb_93cXaj6eKvWaYnFQznvFOu58oA/view?usp=sharing) but instead the last black section and half of the green section are being cropped of the image, [here is how it looks like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/173Ec9ZC2e2EtgJjFUOsd2EAI5W5ZKwXk/view?usp=sharing.)

Both images are scrolled to the end, if i try to scroll down more nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue in this way and its working fantastic.

`<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} style={{ flex: 1,}} >`

make your parent view scrollView and and apply these attributes on this, it will stretch the view on full screen on both android and ios platform.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to fix it - add padding to `contentContainerStyle`

like this ( in my case `ScrollView` is horizontal and i add `paddingRight`, in vertical it may be `paddingBottom` )

```
 <ScrollView 
   horizontal
   style={styles.someStyle} 
   contentContainerStyle={{ paddingRight: 20 }} // 20 or what your need
 >
```